# Passing current location ( longitude and latitude ) in the Google Places API

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-places-api

am trying to integrate Google Places API into my  app.
Now I am finding out my current location of the Phone, how do I embed the longitude and latitude which I have got into the following URL instead of "location=34.0522222,-118.2427778"

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=restaurants&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean how do you do string manipulation such as (untested):

```
int latitude = ...;
int longitude = ...;
String preamble = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=";
String postamble = "&radius=500&types=restaurants&sensor=true&key=";
String key = "Your_api_key";
String latStr = latitude + "";
String longStr = longitude + "";
String url = preamble + latStr + "," + longStr + postamble + key;
```

Comment: the value which i get is in integer/double type....and want to embedd that latitude and longitude in the URL...   the solution which you provide is it working.... Between thank for the reply

Comment: I updated the untested example to show one way to convert from an integer to a String (fairly basic Java).

Comment: I am trying to use GenericUrl class to add the latitude and longitude to url ..but how actually to use it....because its not importing any package as such.....

Comment: when using the above thing its showwing null results and STATUS CODE AS "INVALID REQUEST"

Answer (score 0):

```
$lat = location[0];
$long = location[1];
```

Should work, but I use json for geting long and lat from google. Is better. I can check it again if not working.

Here is better json solution:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Atlantis&sensor=true&oe=utf-8

You should change Atlantis to address

Comment: I am trying to use GenericUrl class to add the latitude and longitude to url ..but how actually to use it....because its not importing any package as such.....